# i have written a python code to find maximum element in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

can you tell me the time complexity of the code, I am using the divide and conquer technique?

```
def max_of_list(l):
  if(len(l)==1):
    return l[0]
  else:
    left_max=max_of_list(l[:len(l)//2])
    righ_max=max_of_list(l[len(l)//2:])
    return max(left_max,righ_max)
```

Comment: **list is not sorted**

Comment: You end up calling the built-in `max` anyway -- why not just call it for the whole list?

Comment: i am using in only for 2 values

Comment: i am not able to find time complexity , i think this is of log(n)

Comment: It's actually O(n), there is no algorithm with a lower bound for the problem of selection in an unordered array using only comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the master theorem since this is a recursive algorithm:

T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)

a: number of subproblems

b: size reduction of subproblems

f(n): complexity of split/join of subproblems process

This algorithm is recursive heavy, since f(n) the process of split/joining has complexity O(1). As such the complexity of the algorithm is O(n^c) where c is the critical exponent and is given by:

c = log(a) / log(b)

In this particular case:

c = log(2)/log(2) = 1

Thus, the complexity of the algorithm is linear: e.g. O(n)

You can read more about the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_%28analysis_of_algorithms%29?wprov=sfla1)